# how to distribute python app with glade GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, distutils, glade

I'm trying to distribute this app that I wrote in python. The application consists of 2 python scripts. 2 `.glade` files and 1 `.png` file.

Here is my dir structure on this project

```
vasm/
    vasmcc.py
    src/
       vasm.py
    gui/
       vasm.glade
       vasmset.glade
       logo.png
```

`vasmcc` is just the python script for the gui... the real python module would be `vasm.py`.

My question is, how do I distribute this so that it includes the `.glade` and the `.png` files?

By distribute I mean provide an installable source package that can be installed on to another system.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "distribute"? In other words, what more do you want to do than just putting it all into one .tar.gz file?

Comment: I want to put it in a .tar.gz file but want a way to install it on the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [distutils](http://docs.python.org/library/distutils.html). You can tell it to install all kinds of files, not just the source code itself. For the user, installing your program then comes down to

```
$ python setup.py install
```

and it's even pretty easy to, say, create RPM packages with distutils.

Comment: I've been looking at it... but have no idea where or how to tell it to install the .glade files and where to put them.

Comment: That's what the package data is for: http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data